# aspnet_regIIS.exe -i does not add aspx to scriptmaps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

After installing asp.net (and aspnet_regIIS.exe -i) the site doesn't accept my default.aspx page. When trying to access it I get a 404.
When hitting directly to my mvc pages (/search.mvc for example) it works like a charm.

We checked the website configuration and noted that there are no .aspx references in the scriptmaps node.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

We added a single session manually (for aspx.net) with the wrong -old- version of asp.net engine and then ran aspnet_regiis.exe and now it added all the old lines too.

Don't have a clue why and when and how. Mistery...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the .aspx references in the scriptmaps. SCNR. ;-)

More seriously, are they there at the "Web Sites" properties level in IIS manager? What is the output you get when running `aspnet_regIIS.exe -i`?

Mine says:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
Start installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
..............................
Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the entries for aspx (and a bunch of other extentions linked to the asp.net) are not there. Neither as inherited (at the "web sites" level) or the level of the web site itself.

After running aspnet_regIIS.exe -i it returns to the regular prompt.

Comment: We got the exact same answer.
In the mean time we even tried the 1.x version, same there (except for no '...'s there.